# VBA not working properly when using "for" loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which read 2 workbooks and puts a vlookup function

But the problem is that when using two for loops, it is(i guess) getting confused which variable to take first.
What i want is it should take ZS7_656.xls and NSA_103_A.xls first
But it is taking ZS7_656 and DCA_656_A and vlookup is not coming properly

Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Prod = Array("ZS7_656", "PCO_656")
    Dev = Array("NSA_103", "DCA_656")
    For lngCounter1 = LBound(Dev) To UBound(Dev)
        For lngCounter = LBound(Prod) To UBound(Prod)

            Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & Prod(lngCounter) & ".xls")
            Set Z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & Dev(lngCounter1) & "_A.xls")

            With x.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter))
                Set aCell1 = .Range("A1:X1000") _
                    .Find(What:="User", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                .Range(aCell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, aCell1.Column).End(xlUp)) _
                    .Offset(2, 0) _
                    .Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter)).Range("A2")
            End With

            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter)).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            LastRow2 = Z.Sheets(Dev(lngCounter1) & "_A").Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            Set Table1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter)).Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            Set Table3 = Z.Sheets(Dev(lngCounter1) & "_A").Range("B1:B" & LastRow2)
            A1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter)).Range("K2").Row
            A2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter)).Range("K2").Column
            For Each Item In Table1
                On Error Resume Next
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter)).Cells(A1, A2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Table3, 1, False)
                On Error GoTo 0
                A1 = A1 + 1
            Next Item

            x.Close
            Z.Close
        Next lngCounter
    Next lngCounter1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why dont you make your life easier and divide your loops into functions?

Comment: bcoz i dont like that :)
Also, i prefer using for loops

Comment: Then good luck finding error... _i dont like that_ its a matter of good/bad code design...not something that you like or dont like

Comment: agreed!!
i wrote the code so that someone could edit it and give me a solution
if i wud be knowing how to use functions, then why will i be using for loops :)

Comment: Loops and functions aren't mutually exclusive. At all.

Comment: hey mat's Mug
i have indented it now.
is there something wrong in my for loop?

Comment: You should use `Option Explicit` and define your variables.

Comment: You seem to be switching between `x.Sheets` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` quite a bit: it might make more sense to define some `Worksheet` objects (`Set wsX = x.Sheets(Prod(lngCounter))` for example) to avoid some confusion there. `ThisWorkbook` seems like it could lead to problems when working with multiple workbooks

Comment: Your `For` loop is doing `(D0, P0), (D0, P1), (D1, P0), (D1, P1)`.  You just need one line of `For` loop to do the trick so it would be `(D0, P0), (D1, P1)`.  If I understand what you are trying to do correctly.

Comment: @J.Fox `ThisWorkbook` always consistently and unambiguously refers to the workbook that's running the code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I know, but it can be easy to get confused, especially when you're using full sheet declarations every line. Best practice is to define all worksheets and workbooks ([Always define and set references to all Workbooks and Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=201708291405057158212))

Comment: @ian0411 : you are absolutely right!!
i want to do  (D0, P0), (D1, P1) in one for loop
how can i merge the both??

Comment: If your array will be always the same length, just add a counter like `counter = UBound(Prod)` and replace both `Dev(lngCounter1)` and `Prod(lngCounter)` with this variable, and remove that redundant `FOR` loop.

Comment: @J.Fox if the workbook you're working with is `ThisWorkbook` then defining an object variable for every sheet is NOT best practice. The most robust way is to use worksheets' `CodeName` and thus *use* the globally-scoped object variables VBA defines for you automatically, e.g. `Sheet1`. Dereferencing `Sheet1` when you already have a readily available object for it is redundant and wasteful, not best practice. Ditto for `ThisWorkbook`, which is absolutely unambiguous, contrary to `ActiveWorkbook`/`ActiveSheet` that are implicitly referenced whenever one doesn't qualify e.g. a `Range` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have data to test but this is what you can try the first step:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Prod As Variant
    Dim Dev As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Prod = Array("ZS7_656", "PCO_656")
    Dev = Array("NSA_103", "DCA_656")
    counter = UBound(Prod)
    i = 0

    For i = 0 To counter

        Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & Prod(counter) & ".xls")
        Set Z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & Dev(counter) & "_A.xls")

        With x.Sheets(Prod(counter))
            Set aCell1 = .Range("A1:X1000") _
                .Find(What:="User", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Range(aCell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, aCell1.Column).End(xlUp)) _
                .Offset(2, 0) _
                .Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(counter)).Range("A2")
        End With

        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(counter)).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        LastRow2 = Z.Sheets(Dev(counter) & "_A").Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set Table1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(counter)).Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        Set Table3 = Z.Sheets(Dev(counter) & "_A").Range("B1:B" & LastRow2)
        A1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(counter)).Range("K2").Row
        A2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(counter)).Range("K2").Column
        For Each Item In Table1
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(counter)).Cells(A1, A2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Item, Table3, 1, False)
            On Error GoTo 0
            A1 = A1 + 1
        Next Item

        x.Close
        Z.Close
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Great brotha!!
exactly what i needed for :)
i did not try yet but the logic is now cleared to me.
thanx for your help

Comment: Glad to help.  But sorry that I couldn't test the code before giving to you so you might see errors here and there.  And hopefully this will give you a good start and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's excessively hard to figure out exactly what your code is doing. You're using cryptic names and convoluted ways to do things, not to mention none of the variables are declared.

With the help of my [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) I refactored your code a bit (mostly renaming undeclared variables), added `Option Explicit`, and declared all locals.

Notice how meaningful names go a long way towards making code easier to maintain:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim prodBookNames() As String
    prodBookNames = Array("ZS7_656", "PCO_656")
    Dim devBookNames() As String
    devBookNames = Array("NSA_103", "DCA_656")

    Dim devBookIndex As Long
    For devBookIndex = LBound(devBookNames) To UBound(devBookNames)
        Dim prodBookIndex As Long
        For prodBookIndex = LBound(prodBookNames) To UBound(prodBookNames)

            Dim devBook As Workbook
            Set devBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & devBookNames(devBookIndex) & "_A.xls")

            Dim prodBook As Workbook
            Set prodBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & prodBookNames(prodBookIndex) & ".xls")

            With prodBook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex))
                Dim aCell1 As Range 'whatever that means
                Set aCell1 = .Range("A1:X1000").Find(What:="User", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                'BUG: Range.Find may return Nothing, causing run-time error 91 here.
                .Range(aCell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, aCell1.Column).End(xlUp)) _
                    .Offset(2, 0) _
                    .Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex)).Range("A2")
            End With

            'BUG: Range.Find may return Nothing, causing run-time error 91 here.
            Dim prodLastRow As Long
            prodLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex)).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            'BUG: Range.Find may return Nothing, causing run-time error 91 here.
            Dim devLastRow As Long
            devLastRow = devBook.Sheets(devBookNames(devBookIndex) & "_A").Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

            Dim prodColumnA As Range
            Set prodColumnA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex)).Range("A2:A" & prodLastRow)

            Dim devColumnB As Range
            Set devColumnB = devBook.Sheets(devBookNames(devBookIndex) & "_A").Range("B1:B" & devLastRow)

            'NOTE: initialized to constant value 2
            Dim prodCurrentRow As Long
            prodCurrentRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex)).Range("K2").Row
            'NOTE: initialized to constant value 11
            Dim prodCurrentColumn As Long
            prodCurrentColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex)).Range("K2").Column

            Dim item As Range
            For Each item In prodColumnA
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(prodBookNames(prodBookIndex)).Cells(prodCurrentRow, prodCurrentColumn) = Application.VLookup(item, devColumnB, 1, False)
                prodCurrentRow = prodCurrentRow + 1
            Next item

            prodBook.Close
            devBook.Close

        Next prodBookIndex
    Next devBookIndex
End Sub
```

Note, I've replaced the `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` call (from which you're ignoring lookup errors) with the late-bound `Application.VLookup` equivalent, which *returns* error values instead of *raising run-time errors* - it's a bit less VBA-idiomatic, but then you don't need to pretend no error happened when no errors happen.

[As was noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940524/vba-not-working-properly-when-using-for-loop#comment78840357_45940524), your nested loops are doing `(D0, P0), (D0, P1), (D1, P0), (D1, P1)`. If you need `Dx` and `Px` to use the same indexing, then you only need one loop.

The problem is that this leaves you with potentially mismatched "twin arrays", when conceptually what you need is a "bunch of pairs". Turns out there's a data structure that's exactly meant for storing a "bunch of pairs" - look into what `Scripting.Dictionary` can do for you.

```
Dim pairs As Scripting.Dictionary
Set pairs = New Scripting.Dictionary
With pairs
    .Add "ZS7_656", "NSA_103"
    .Add "PCO_656", "DCA_656"
End With
```

And then you can iterate the dictionary's `Keys` array, and retrieve the associated *value* for each *key* you're iterating: much more robust than "twin arrays", which are a code smell in any language.

```
Dim keys As Variant
keys = pairs.keys
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)

    Dim prodBookName As String
    prodBookName = keys(i)

    Dim devBookName As String
    devBookName = pairs(prodBookName)

    'loop body

Next
```

Comment: i tested the code @Mat's Mug
and again, it is showing the same result as mine. no change

Comment: @AnirudhChauhan yes, that's the entire point of *refactoring*. Refactorings that change code's behavior is called *refuctoring*, which I don't do. Did you even *read* the answer? Or you were expecting me to do all the work for you and copy+pasta your way to proper code? Not going to happen.

Comment: i just wanted to know how should i change my for loops
thats all i asked for man
anywyz thanx for "refractoring" my code.

Comment: @AnirudhChauhan I've added more information about what the final code should look like using a `Scripting.Dictionary` (from the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* type library, which you can add in Tools > References), but don't expect a readily copy-pastable answer from me. I think it's pretty clear you only need one single loop from this answer.

Comment: @Downvoter feedback is always appreciated; telling me what's wrong with this answer allows me to edit it to improve it. Downvote-and-run serves no one.

Comment: @ian0411 countered ;-)